# What Steps do you Take to Troubleshoot Problems with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, debugging, http, curl

Almost any working PHP programmer has faced having to use CURL to send raw HTTP requests, whether it's for credit card payment processing, nefarious screen scraping, or something in-between.

Almost any forum where PHP programmers congregate has a large number of people who [can't get the cURL functions to do what they want](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/curl).

When cURL isn't working for you, what troubleshooting techniques do you use to figure out why it isn't working?  What weird gotchas with PHP's curl implementation have you run into?  If someone asks a "HALP MY CURL IZ BROKEN" question on a forum, what are the steps you take to figure out why their request isn't working?

Comment: just use CURLOPT_HEADER to get the header.. No need for that function

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find the CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT option to be very useful.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init('http://www.php.net');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, 'dbg_curl_data');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

curl_exec($curl);

echo '<fieldset><legend>request headers</legend>
  <pre>', htmlspecialchars(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)), '</pre>
</fieldset>';

echo '<fieldset><legend>response</legend>
  <pre>', htmlspecialchars(dbg_curl_data(null)), '</pre>
</fieldset>';

function dbg_curl_data($curl, $data=null) {
  static $buffer = '';

  if ( is_null($curl) ) {
    $r = $buffer;
    $buffer = '';
    return $r;
  }
  else {
    $buffer .= $data;
    return strlen($data);
  }
}
```

Comment: is this works on post data also?? i m getting error `Warning: curl_exec() [function.curl-exec]: Could not call the CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION in C:\xampp\htdocs\my_project\login.php` where on ine 49 there is written `$res=curl_exec($curl);`

Comment: Yes, it works with POST data as well. Looks like the function name you've passed to curl_setopt/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION doesn't actually resolve to a function/callable.

Comment: Wow, this was a very clean and efficient solution. Really helped me out tons, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I never use CURL (in php). The PHP stream api is much neater, and can be used to POST data as well. [Wez Furlong](http://netevil.org/blog/2006/nov/http-post-from-php-without-curl) has an article about this.

If I were to use it? I'd start with turning on all messages (setting error reporting to E_ALL). If I find that PHP doesn't tell me what I need in the error messages, I'd probably use a proxy approach to see what's actually going on. Changing the target url to a local php page containing something like

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_SERVER);
```

is one way. Another way is to use a utility like netcat to listen on port 80 and send the request there:

```
netcat -l -p 80
```

This won't return anything to curl, but it will allow you to see exactly what is sent the server, which might be enough to diagnose the problem.

You can also retrieve the headers from PHP using the [apache_request_headers()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apache-request-headers.php) function. In most cases I prefer the netcat approach, though, since it guarantees that I see the unmodified truth, and also display the raw post data.

Comment: That's a great point about the stream library.  Are the stream functions available if the fopen url wrappers are off?

Comment: The stream functions are probably available, but the example I linked to still requires the actual connection to be done using fopen(), which means that it won't work with allow_url_fopen turned off. If that's the case you're doomed to use curl. Personally, I always turn it on, and avoid making the mistakes that turns url fopen into a security issue from the beginning. :)

Comment: I definitely like the stream api. As a side note: php (or the curl extension) can be compiled to use curl as handler for some url wrappers.

Comment: Aye, the whole fopen url wrapper issue will likely prevent the stream functions from ever dislodging curl as the default way to make http requests with PHP.