# php curl is not fetching the data from youtube API

Tags: php, curl, youtube

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Php - Debugging Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl)

I am using curl to fetch the user data from youtube API 
The code is

```
    $url_userInfo =  'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?access_token=ya29.AHES6ZS7GMdZf91LbMtoOdhFSFOpTuHHT-t7pSggAp-tS0A;

print_r($url_userInfo);
$ch = curl_init($url_userInfo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, '3');
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r( $content);
```

If I manually visit this url it displays the data in xml form. but there is nothing to print in `$content`.

Is there any problem with code??

Comment: Unable to reproduce: *"Notice:  Undefined variable: ytAccessToken" - please only provide working examples, e.g. provide testing or demo credentials.

Comment: now try. it will work for an hour

Comment: I tried, you just need to troubleshoot it. It's trivial, see the linked question. Please do your homework before posting a new question  and always add debug information if you run into a problem. Also please see [What Steps do you Take to Troubleshoot Problems with PHP cURL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815910/what-steps-do-you-take-to-troubleshoot-problems-with-php-curl)

Comment: You can **not** access SSL protected sites with cURL as default, you should be using a list of trusted certificates to do this, see this [article](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/) on the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's actually a **HTTPS** link, i.e. it uses SSL, and you need to get cacert.pem, and set up cURL for SSL to make that work.

You can get the certificate **[here!](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)**

and you would set it up like so:

```
$curl = curl_init();
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
$header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $browser);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); //needed for SSL
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/scripts/cacert.pem"); //path to file
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_userInfo);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);  //display errors under development
curl_close($ch);
print_r( $content );
```

Using a proper user agent, and authenticating with SSL and a certificate, just like the browser would.

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman - I added an `echo error` statement, try that and see what errors there are. Did you download the certificate and place it on the server with the correct path etc.

Comment: Try increasing the `CONNECTTIMEOUT`, right now it's 2 seconds, which should be enough, as any more than 2 seconds for establishing a connection usually means the URL is not correct, but try increasing that number to 20 seconds and see if it connects or not.

Comment: If your printing it to a browser, you'll probably have to use "view source" to see the tags etc.