# How do I troubleshoot Curl in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I have never used Curl but I am trying to complete a self api project at my job just to gain some experience.
And I am stuck on the first step... I want to authenticate with an api.
So I am running this code and **I expect to see a Success 200 response with my access token, etc** but I get nothing.
**No error, no feedback, the page just opens up blank**
I have tired to use CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT from this page [What Steps do you Take to Troubleshoot Problems with PHP cURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815910/what-steps-do-you-take-to-troubleshoot-problems-with-php-curl) but still I got a blank page

Anyway thank you to anyone in advantage for some tips

```
<?php
const TOKEN_ENDPOINT  = 'xxxxxx';
const GRANT_TYPE      = 'xxxxx';
const CLIENTID        = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';
const CLIENTSECRET    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const USERNAME        = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
const PASSWORD        = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$clientCredentials = base64_encode(CLIENTID . ':' . CLIENTSECRET);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => TOKEN_ENDPOINT,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'grant_type=' . GRANT_TYPE . '&username=' . USERNAME . '&password=' . PASSWORD ,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Authorization: Basic ' . $clientCredentials
  ),
));


$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response ;
?>
```

Comment: What's the HTTP status code?

Comment: No, that would be the payload of the response... try `$http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` after curl_exec()

Comment: [curl_getinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) is your friend.

Comment: I checked F12 and found  under the network tab, the HTTP status code 200 but to my server which is where this page lives. I don't see anything related to the api endpoints

Comment: Nothing in your server's error log?

Comment: Thanks Honk and Alex, I have tried to implement curl_getinfo as described but still nothing. I will continue trying...

Comment: You need to send the request as curl does... check out Postman (google it!), a tool with which you can make those calls very easily.

Comment: Ok so I got it working in Postman but still nothing on my php page. I have keep trying to get curl_getinfo to work and now when I echo $http_status I get 0  Slowly but surely we will endure

Answer (score 1):

To check curl error, the best way is to use `curl_error` function

```
$response = curl_exec($curl);
if (curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_msg = curl_error($curl);
}
curl_close($curl);
echo $response ;
```

[See the description of libcurl error codes here](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

[See the description of PHP curl_errno() function here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php)

[See the description of PHP curl_error() function here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Answer (score 0):

When all else fails, i do this (code snippet from my ApiHelper curl wrapper).  Use your own logger or evidence printing mechanism. Most every time the answer to the puzzle is in the printed stuff :

```
        // we simply stream curlopt debug info to a temporary 
        // file, so we can log it out later (when helper is set
        // to verbose)
        $st       = microtime(true);
        $verbiage = null;
        if ($this->verbose) {
            // write out the curl debug stuff
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT , false);
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_VERBOSE , true);
            $verbiage = fopen('php://temp' , 'w+');
            curl_setopt($ch , CURLOPT_STDERR , $verbiage);
        }

        $resp                = curl_exec($ch);
        $end                 = microtime(true);           // get as float
        $delta               = 1000.0 * ($end - $st);    // treat as float
        $this->roundTripInMs = sprintf("%.2f" , $delta);
        $this->getInstanceLogger()->debug("WS call : round trip took " . sprintf("%.2f" , $delta) . " ms.");
     
        if ($this->verbose) {
            // rewind and log the verbose output
            rewind($verbiage);
            $verboseLog = stream_get_contents($verbiage);
            $this->getInstanceLogger()->info("Verbose cURL : \n$verboseLog");
            fclose($verbiage);
        }
        $this->curlinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
        $this->verbose && $this->getInstanceLogger()->info("cURL info : \n" . json_encode($this->curlinfo , PEHR_PRETTY_JSON));
        $this->httpStatus = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE);
        if (!$resp) {
            if ($this->verbose) $this->getInstanceLogger()->error("CURL request to [$url] failed\n" . json_encode($this->curlinfo , PEHR_PRETTY_JSON));
            return 0;
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        if ($resp && $this->verbose) $this->getInstanceLogger()->debug("Received json \n" . $resp);
```